# Existence and uniqueness of solution for an eliptic problem.

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset R^n$ be an open and bounded set with smooth boundary and $f \in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\overline{\Omega})$. Let $ a \geq 0$ be a constant.

> Consider the following problem:
>
> $$ \left\{ \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  -\Delta u +au = f ,  \  in  \ \Omega   \\ \ u=0 , \ in \ \partial\Omega \\ \end{array} \right. $$

Can someone give me a reference for the proof of the existence of classical solution for this problem?

In this text http://www3.nd.edu/~qhan/PDE.pdf, it discusses maximum principles about the problem that I said above. but I haven't found a book with the proof of the existence.

Comment: Is there nothing about $f$ on the boundary?

Comment: Yes. I forget : $f \in C(\overline{\Omega})$ . sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f\in C(\overline{\Omega})$ implies that $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ which implies that there exist unique weak solution $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)$.

Moreover, $f\in C(\overline{\Omega})$ implies that $f\in L^p(\Omega)$ for all $p$, which implies that $u\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)\cap W^{2,p}(\Omega)$ for all $p$ (see Theorem 9.32 of [Brezis](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbbs.sciencenet.cn%2Fupload%2Fblog%2Ffile%2F2010%2F12%2F2010127131928961750.pdf&ei=c51ZUpmuBZWj4APi9oCACA&usg=AFQjCNGEZbxtZ-a_IyE9kq11fdflkeqvEg&bvm=bv.53899372,d.dmg) book).

We conclude from the last paragraph that $u\in C^{1,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$ for some $\alpha\in (0,1)$. To conclude note that $f\in C^2(\Omega)$ implies interior regularity (see section 9.6 of Brezis book) and therefore $u\in C^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: for the implication $f \in C^{2}(\Omega)$ implies $u \in C^2 (\Omega)$ wich theorem do you used of the section 9.6 ?

Comment: I suggest you to read all of the section 9.6. After it, I think you gonna find it.

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada por cima na seção. aí fiquei com medo de a justificativa para a implicacao que falei acima ser algo muito escondido na seção. Olharei a seçao com mais calma . obrigado pela ajuda !

Comment: De nada, pode procurar la que vc acha, tá no meio de uma demonstração.

Comment: Em relação a justificativa: por acaso a justificativa é a hipoeliticidade mencionada na observação 25?